# Delete subtree in AST after testing that it exists in ANTLRv4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST from an ANTLR grammar "Mygrammar" and i want to delete the node (with its children) corresponding to the rule "myrule" after testing that "myrule" exists in the AST. I wonder if there's a way to do it by overriding the entermyrule () method from the MygrammarBaseListener or visitmyrule () from MygrammarBaseVisitor since using remove last child () doesn't work.
If you could provide any hint or ressources to look at since the documentation didn't help me, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: You can [delete](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrTreeEditing/blob/fd7ec0a58c244107be9a0dcab1ed69c73fba9346/TreeEdits.cs#L197) nodes in the *concrete syntax tree* by casting to ParserRuleContext, then removing the node you want from the children array. However, you must be careful to do that in the parent of the node being deleted from within a tree walker as to not violate immutable enumerators. You will need to test the node you want to delete in the visit of the parent.

Comment: @kaby76 i'm new to antlr so can you please clarify a little bit about casting to ParserRuleContext and the children array.

Comment: Please follow the link I gave, which is for the C# target, and shows how to delete a node in the tree. Type casting may be required for your target language C#, Java, Go, etc.

Comment: @kaby76 When you say "you must be careful...enumerators", you mean that i should do something like this : ParseTree tree = parser.myrule();
       ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
       MyListener listener = new MyListener(parser);
       walker.walk(listener, tree);  where Mylistener overrides enterParentmyrule () (the parent of the node containing "my rule") by  casting to ParserRuleContext and removing the node from the children array as you said. Is that right ?

Comment: Correct. That sounds like what you need to do. In C#, if you modify a list while iterating over it, that will cause an exception. That is what I was alluding to.

Comment: @kaby76 Sorry to bother you again. In the code you linked, it's this part   t.Parent = null; c.children.RemoveAt(i); that performes the node deletion that i need but i don't find "RemoveAt" as an antlr method. Am i doing something wrong? (i'm using java)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)